# ¿como hago un consulta de lo que lee el RFID-RC522 en Mysql desde python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

tengo el sensor RFID que lee una tarjeta obteniendo este tipo de dato:

```
 [146,221,210,42,13]
```

cuando consulto de esta forma:

```
consulta="SELECT nombres FROM user WHERE uid='[146,221,210,42,13]';"
```

me trae el el dato correspndiente del registro asociado a ese codigo en la tabla user

pero esta lectura es variable, por la cual la guardo  en una variable llamada tarjeta y al hacer la consulta me trae un registro vacio

```
tarjeta=uid
consulta="SELECT nombres FROM user WHERE uid=tarjeta;"
```

entonces me queda claro que estoy haciendo mal la consulta, pregunto:
¿Cómo debo hacer la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que le di fue esta, Converti la lectura del sensor de esta manera:

```
card_id = str(uid[0]) + "." + str(uid[1]) + "." + str(uid[2]) + "." + str(uid[3])+ "." + str(uid[4])
```

y luego consulte asi:

```
consulta="SELECT nombres FROM user WHERE uid='" + card_id + "';" 
cursor.execute(consulta)
```

y en la base de datos cambie los valores guardado de esto:

```
[146,221,210,42,13]
```

a esto

```
146.221.210.42.13
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta con:

```
tarjeta=uid
consulta="SELECT nombres FROM user WHERE uid=\'%s\';" % tarjeta
```